# Install Google Chrome Canary on Android/IPhone

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am working on HTML 5 Web Audio Input project. I want to test the project in android/Iphone but I researched that it only works in Google Chrome Canary. I am unable to find canary on Play Store/App Store. Can anybody give me the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chrome Canary (Unstable)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.canary) is now available for Android on Google Play.

Unfortunately, it is not available on the iOS App Store yet. However, you can use [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode) in Chrome (including Canary) to emulate browsing on an iPhone.

Comment: It means I cant test on actual device?

Comment: Unfortunately, for Canary-only features, no. At least, not until they reach Chrome Beta. But using Device Mode in Chrome Canary should come close.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to find it out.

Comment: Canary is now available on Android too.

Answer (score 0):

Searching Play Store for 'Chrome' should return results for all three Chrome channels. Please note that unlike desktop, the Canary channel is called 'DEV' and uses an icon similar to the stable version.